# gnome-keyring: couldn't find any place to import files

Tags: security, gnome, key-authentication, certificates, gnome-keyring

I need to use a client certificate. I was able to import it successfully on Windows and Mac, however when I am trying to import it on Linux I am getting the following error:

```
$ gnome-keyring import ca2.cer
gnome-keyring: couldn't find any place to import files
```

Shall I create the key-ring somehow?

How can I properly import the cert?